# How to join elements of a string array into larger strings joined by spaces to a certain length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of strings in which I would like to join them by spaces, however I don't want to go over X length for each "chunk".

For example:

```
let userList = ["Bill", "Tom", "Micheal", "Steve", "Aa", "Bb", ...] // array of strings i want to "chunk"

// chunkArr(ArrayOfStrings, LengthOfEachChunk)
chunkArr(userList, 10) // -> ["Bill Tom", "Micheal", "Steve Aa", "Bb"] // Each string in the new array has a length less than the LengthOfEachChunk
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `reduce` for this:

```js
function chunkArr(arr, len) {
    return arr.reduce((acc, word, i) => {
        if (!i || acc[acc.length-1].length + word.length >= len) {
            acc.push(word);
        } else {
            acc[acc.length - 1] += " " + word;
        }
        return acc;
    }, []);
}


let userList = ["Bill", "Tom", "Micheal", "Steve", "Aa", "Bb"];
let result = chunkArr(userList, 10) 
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use join() method. This method is can be used for strings and array, and it is used commonly.

MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

```js
let userList = ["Bill", "Tom", "Micheal", "Steve", "Aa", "Bb"]

const joinedUserListWithSpace = userList.join(' '); // USE THIS


const joinedUserListWithDash = userList.join('-');

console.log(joinedUserListWithSpace);
console.log(joinedUserListWithDash);
```